# split string into multiple columns by specific characters

Tags: r, split

```
data <- data.frame(ID = 1, Info = "Zebra fish (one)--Hello; blah", Value = 7)
new_data <- data.frame(ID = 1, CATEGORY = "Zebra Fish", TYPE1 = "one", TYPE2 = "Hello", Value = 7)
```

Is there a function that can convert data to dataWANT? I tried this but it doesn't work

```
# Function to parse the info column
parse_info <- function(info) {
  # Split by parentheses and dashes
  parts1 <- unlist(strsplit(info, "\\(|\\)"))
  category <- trimws(parts1[1])
  type1 <- trimws(parts1[2])
  
  # Further split by dashes and semicolons
  parts2 <- unlist(strsplit(parts1[3], "--|;"))
  type2 <- trimws(parts2[1])
  
  return(c(category, type1, type2))
}

# Apply the function to each row
parsed <- t(apply(data, 1, function(row) {
  c(row['ID'], parse_info(row['Info']), row['Value'])
}))

# Create a new data frame
new_data <- as.data.frame(parsed, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(new_data) <- c("ID", "CATEGORY", "TYPE1", "TYPE2", "VALUE")
```

Comment: Do your strings always come in the format of "CATEGORY (TYPE1)--TYPE2; unwanted"?

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `strcapture` from base R:

```
a <- strcapture("([^(]+) \\(([^)]+)\\)--([^;]+)", data$Info, list(Category='', Type1='', Type2=''))

cbind(subset(data, select = -Info), a)
  ID Value   Category Type1 Type2
1  1     7 Zebra fish   one Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

If your strings always come in the format of "CATEGORY (TYPE1)--TYPE2; unwanted", you can do a `separate_wider_delim` using opening bracket `(`, closing bracket `)` and semicolon `;` as the delimiters.

```r
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(cols = Info, 
                       delim = regex(" \\(|\\)--|;"), 
                       names = c("CATEGORY", "TYPE1", "TYPE2"), 
                       too_many = "drop")

 A tibble: 1 × 5
     ID CATEGORY   TYPE1 TYPE2 Value
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 Zebra fish one   Hello     7
```